# one button calls two different functions on different clicks

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
function one() {
   blah blah blah
}

function two() {
   blah blah blah
}
</script>

<button onclick="one(); two()">Click Me</button>
```

This will call the two functions at the same time. What I want is to call function one() on the first click and then call function two() on the second click. Calls function three() on 3rd click and so on until 7th click

I would prefer to not use jQuery if possible

Comment: why don't you just create a function three() which includes both function one and two and have the button call that instead?

Comment: Have you tried anything? What possible solutions did you come up with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) to accomplish this:

```js
var fn3 = (function() {
  var first = true;
  return function() {
    first ? fn1() : fn2();
    first = !first;
  }
})();

function fn1() {
  console.log(1);
};
function fn2() {
  console.log(2);
};
```

```html
<button onClick="fn3()">click</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution is not too complex, you can just one() and two() from another function.

```js
var callOne = true;

function one() {
   alert('Call one');
}

function two() {
   alert('Call two');
}

function call(){
   if(callOne) one();
  else two();
  callOne = !callOne;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="call();">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple way of doing this is to reassign the onclick value:

```
<button id="clickme">Click Me</button>
<script>
  function one() {
     alert('one clicked');
     document.getElementById('clickme').onclick = two;
  }

  function two() {
   alert('two clicked');
  }

  document.getElementById('clickme').onclick = one;
</script>
```

Using this trick you have the option to disable the button after calling `two()`:

```
document.getElementById('clickme').onclick = null;
```

Toggle the click handler back to `one()`:

```
document.getElementById('clickme').onclick = one;
```

Or do anything else you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do it like bellow

> On click of the button have a function which decides which function to call according to number of times.

```
<button onclick="decideFunction()">Click Me</button>

var times = 0;

var one = function(){
    alert('first time');
}

var two = function(){
    alert('After first');
}

var decideFunction = function(){
    if(times == 0){
        one();
        times++;
    }
     else{
         two();
    }
}
```

So first time it will execute function `one` and second time onwards it will execute function `two`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is defining an extra variable to `false`(or `true`, of course). While our variable is `false`, clicking button calls first function and changes the variable to `true`. On second click, our onclick function checkes the variable value and calls the function which we defined for `true` value.

```
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var x = false; 
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
if(!x){
    alert('function 1');
    x = true;
    }else{
    alert('function 2');
    x = false;
    }  
})
```